# how to divided a vector and get the partition num in R?

Tags: r, partition

I'm programming in R.I need to divided a vector into x partitions(eg,x=4),and get the partition number of the vector, something like this...

```
a <- data.frame(x=1:20)
a$numofpartition<-ifelse(a$x<6,1,ifelse(a$x<11,2,ifelse(a$x<16,3,4)))
```

As the code,I divided a$x into 4 partitions,and get the partition number for each x, any functions in R could do this? Thank you!

Comment: see `?cut` function

Comment: thanks Cath.cut works,